# Наследование в Python

Tags: python, наследование

Столкнулся с проблемой наследования в питоне. Класс `Manager` не видит метода `last_name` (скрин ошибки выкладываю).

Указывается сообщение

> AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'last_name'

В чем может быть проблема?

Есть файл **person.py** и в нем есть класс `Person`.

[image: Здесь видно класс Person]

[image: и скрин файла manager с классом Manager]

Comment: Перенесите, пожалуйста, код из изображений в текст. Сообщение об ошибке тоже можно скопировать и указать в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 2):

В файле **person.py** у функций `last_name` и `rise_pay` неправильный отступ, поэтому они не относятся к классу.

Сделайте у них отступ такой же, как и у метода `__init__`.

Comment: Спасибо заработало! не после джавы как-то не обращал на это внимание.